# Delphi 2009 label problems in Windows7

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-7, label

i'm  developing am aplication in delphi 2009.

in windows xp, this code works fine

```
X := 70;
Label1.Caption :=FloatToStr(X)+' %'; /// (70 %)
```

In Windows 7, same code generates a diferent label `(%  70)`, the position of characters are changing, all operators are going to front.

Comment: My windows 7 and delphi 2009 did not do it :)

Comment: I can't replicate this in D2009, D2010, XE, or XE2. There's something you're missing somewhere.

Comment: Could be some syntax compiling rule ?

Answer (score 1):

Just so that the question has a coherent answer for any future visitors, the issue is the `BiDiMode`. The following screenshot shows a reproduction of the behaviour described in the question.

[image]

This was generated with the following DFM file.

```
object MyForm: TMyForm
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 23
    Height = 13
    BiDiMode = bdLeftToRight
    Caption = '70 %'
    ParentBiDiMode = False
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 5
    Top = 24
    Width = 23
    Height = 13
    BiDiMode = bdRightToLeft
    Caption = '70 %'
    ParentBiDiMode = False
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly, keep the answer for future visitors.
thx

i can't vote up, but this answer is right.

Comment: What you can do is aaccept the answer by  ticking near the top left of the answer. See the [faq]